# Time Series - plot.ts() and multiple graphs

Tags: r, plot, graph

I've seen several threads on the error I have

```
cannot plot more than 10 series as "multiple"
```

But none really explaining (1) What's going on and (2) how to get around it if you have multiple graphs.

I have a 12 different files.
Each file is 1 row of ~240-250 data points.  This is time-series data.  The values range changes from file to file.

I want to make a graph that has them all on one single plot.  So something like par(mfrow=(4,3)).

However, when I use my code, it gives me the above error.

```
for(cand in cands)
{
    par(mfrow=c(4,3))
    for(type in types)
    {
        ## Construct the file name
        curFile = paste(folder, cand, base, type, close, sep="")

        ## Read in the file 
        ts = read.delim(curFile, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE, header=FALSE,     row.names=NULL,fill=TRUE, quote="", comment.char="")
        plot.ts(ts)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First, don't call your time series object "ts". It's like calling your dog "dog". "ts" gets used in the system, and this can lead to confusion.

Have a look at the structure of your "ts" from reading the file. From your description, is the file a single row with 240+ columns? If so, that'll be a problem too.

`read.delim()` is expecting a column-oriented data file, not row-oriented. You'll need to transpose it if this is the case. Something like:

```
my.ts = t(
          read.delim(curFile, sep="\t", stringsAsFactors=FALSE,
                     header=FALSE, row.names=NULL,
                     fill=TRUE, quote="", comment.char="")
        )
my.ts = ts(my.ts)
```

Comment: Doh! That was a really dumb moment.  Also I agree with the ts! That was just a moment of me trying to run through my code quickly and shorten actual names down to something readable without worrying too much about the context.  Thanks for the help!

Comment: Glad it helped! And we all have those "doh" moments. :)